# why is dj-database-url throwing me an error of : a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' and how do i get around this?

Tags: python, django, heroku

so i am a student attempting to create a django based app...my app is finished and im wanting to launch it on heroku. The error message comes when i run:
`python3 manage.py makemigrations`

I am using dj-database-url for the db url and have the env stored as :

`DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))}`

The versions of everything I am using are:

```
chardet==3.0.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2.7
heroku==0.1.4
idna==2.8
psycopg2==2.8.4
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.22.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
stripe==2.40.0
urllib3==1.25.7
```

and the traceback error message I am receiving is :

```
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Jakey Poo\PycharmProjects\artwork\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Jakey Poo\PycharmProjects\artwork\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 325, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\Jakey Poo\PycharmProjects\artwork\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\Jakey Poo\PycharmProjects\artwork\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\Jakey Poo\PycharmProjects\artwork\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\Jakey Poo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Jakey Poo\PycharmProjects\artwork\artwork\settings.py", line 89, in <module>
    DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))}
  File "C:\Users\Jakey Poo\PycharmProjects\artwork\venv\lib\site-packages\dj_database_url.py", line 80, in parse
    if '?' in path and not url.query:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

The code my app is getting stuck on in dj-database-url is :

```
    path = url.path[1:]
    if '?' in path and not url.query:
        path, query = path.split('?', 2)
    else:
        path, query = path, url.query
    query = urlparse.parse_qs(query)
```

I have never used dj-database-url before and im still relatively new to django and python.

What I have tried:

1. I have checked that all my software versions are up to date and compatable
2. I have tried messing with my db url, giving it quotes, removing quotes etc.
3. I have tried changing the syntax in my settings.py from { to [ as suggested by another post.
4. I have tried printing path to see what it returns, but it returns nothing ( I could be putting the print statement in the wrong place, though)

If anyone is needing anymore information please just ask, I think i have covered everything i can already, though.

Comment: My best guess is that `path` contains bytes-like objects, whereas `’?’` is clearly a string, so you’re trying to check if  an object is part of a group of objects of a different type.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile how do i go about fixing the error?

Comment: Well, either both need to be strings, or both need to be bytes-like objects. Try `b’?’`, maybe? I’m not entirely certain.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile you will have to forgive me, but i have no idea what that means. the code its getting stuck on is dj-database-url code, that isnt my own.

Comment: This isn't how you are supposed to use `dj_database_url`. You shouldn't call parse or pass the env var; you just do `'default': dj_database_url.config()`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman oh really? This was how i was told to set it out from my tutor. do i leave the parameters empty?

Comment: Yes. But that is not actually the problem; the problem is that for some reason Python is returning your env var as a bytestring instead of a normal (unicode) string. I can't quite see why that is.

Comment: @DanielRoseman me neither mate haha. first time using this and its been a nightmare so far. although when i run the above code you suggested, the error doesnt persist, i just get a new error linking to my .env file now. trying to figure that out. Thank you though

Comment: Aha, so presumably you're using something like dotenv? I guess that has something to do with the problem.

Comment: yeah i was using dotenv, i was loading the .env file at the end of my settings.py, not at the top... all sorted and the migration was successfull :)

Comment: Digital Ocean's "Deploy Django App" tutorial for their App Platform (which runs heroku in the background) instructs to use: `'default': dj_database_url.parse(os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')),` and ends up throwing the same error as OP during build.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly where the problem lies in `dj_database_url` but reading through their github issues I think it's a problem with some characters contained in the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable.

In your `settings.py` try using this instead of `dj_database_url.parse()`:

```
... other config settings ...
DATABASE_URL = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(),
}
```

`config()` should automatically use the `DATABASE_URL` setting by default, so simply setting it from your environment variable first and then calling `config()` after should bypass whatever problem the `parse()` method in handling the url.